# How to add templateURL on condition from service in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a component which has templateURL. Based on the service true or false it should load. for example first time it service with variable load = true, so templateURL should load. Next time I will set load=false. After this if I call the component again templateURL should not load. How can I achieve this. I want HTML should be remain same in second click, instead of reintialize.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can show/hide your html div based on variable *load*. 
Supposing you have html file named `mycomponent.html` in templateUrl

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './mycomponent.html'
})
```

Your html file should be something like this

```
<div *ngIf="load">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: No, my case is whenever I click the component link I should get first time entered HTML. it should not load again.